# closed form solution for $ \displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{k-1} {\frac{1}{x(k-x)}} $

Tags: real-analysis, closed-form

Is there any closed form solution for this summation?

$$ \sum_{x=1}^{k-1} {\frac{1}{x(k-x)}} $$

$k$ is a finite integer constant.

Comment: What is $k$ here?

Comment: @B.Pasternak k is an integer constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that $\frac{1}{x(k-x)} = \frac{1}{k} \left( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{k-x} \right)$.  Therefore,
$$\sum_{x=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{x(k-x)} = \frac{1}{k} \left( \sum_{x=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{x=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-x} \right).$$
By reversing the order of summation in the second sum, we get that this is equal to $\frac{2}{k} H_{n-1}$, where $H_{n-1} = \sum_{x=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{x}$ is the harmonic sum.  (There is no simpler closed-form expression for $H_n$, though a great deal is known about it.)

Comment: Beat me to it. +1.